# How to reach 100% code coverage with expectexception in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I'm testing that, given an input that must fail, handleMatchResults will throw a RouteNotFoundException. This is the actual test's code:

```
public function test_not_found_match_throws_NotFoundException()
{
    $this->expectException(RouteNotFoundException::class);
    $request = $this->prophet->prophesize(ServerRequest::class);
    $this->router->handleMatchResults([0, []], $request->reveal());
}
```

Everything goes as expected, my test pass, but, when I run phpunit --coverage-text (or any other coverage type) I have that, the last line of this test, and the last line of another similar test, are unreachable/not-executed. I can understand that those are not executed because, if the code is correct, the last line of this test won't be ever executed because

`$this->router->handleMatchResults([0, []], $request->reveal());`

Will always throw an exception and the execution of the function will end. So, how do I reach 100% coverage of my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you wont get 100%, because metric should not be on your TEST.
You should use [whitelist or blacklist](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.whitelisting-files) in configuration, to ommit this tests.

> It is mandatory to configure a whitelist for telling PHPUnit which
>   sourcecode files to include in the code coverage report.

```
<filter>
  <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
    <directory suffix=".php">/path/to/files</directory>
    <file>/path/to/file</file>
    <exclude>
      <directory suffix=".php">/path/to/files</directory>
      <file>/path/to/file</file>
    </exclude>
  </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Your code will mark, that went to `handleMatchResults` and execute `throw`. In other test, you will execute positive scenario with this function.

That way you should have 100% coverage.

Comment: Thank you. I already have a test case that won't throw an exception. Anyways, I've just told to phpunit to ignore the test method and I've once again 100% test coverage.

Comment: @FrOz: To check which code is covered by the tests, only cover the units (see @covers annotation). Also whitelist *all* test code as you want to see which code is covered (and not which test-code). Do code-coverage of your tests to see if you have dead code in your tests. Like in the example with your question here, the test does too much. Extract one test that tests for the exception, do that by catching the expected exception and make the test fail otherwise (`$this->fail('an expected exception was not thrown');` or similar).